# How can I send Firebase Push Notification between two different android Application?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

For Example I want to send push notification from Device "X" with Application "X" to Device "Y" with application "Y" how I can achieve that?
I am using Firebase Cloud messaging service.

Comment: would users have both apps installed on same device?

Comment: no, will be two different devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple Applications to a single Firebase project. From you comments a single user would have just one App of those two. That means you can just add the second App to the same project and continue on with the messaging setup as you did it with the first one. You would anyway save the notification tokens on your Firebase database. Additionaly you could save them separately for each App if in future it happens that a single user installs both apps. With those notification tokens you decied on what app and what device to send the notification.

Comment: ok, I got you. the server key for both application will be same. Right? I tried to save the token in a map variable where I and tried to send but not working for me. may be my approach is wrong as I am newbie.

Comment: You can also create multiple server keys for each app.

Comment: what happens if both app will subscribe with same token? In that case does the both app will receive same notification